Although nn.Linear mismatch the input tensor size， Training is still running normally without any mismatch error
The following two programs run on CPU and GPU respectively, and it is obvious that the tensor size is different from the requirements of the model.
GPU:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.cuda.empty_cache()
linear_layer = nn.Linear(**10**, 5).to('cuda')

batch_size = 32
input_tensor = torch.randn(batch_size, **12**).to('cuda')

output_tensor = linear_layer(input_tensor)

print("input tensor size：", input_tensor.shape)
print("output tensor size：", output_tensor.shape)

Pycharm is running normally without any errors
CPU:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.cuda.empty_cache()
linear_layer = nn.Linear(**10**, 5)

batch_size = 32
input_tensor = torch.randn(batch_size, **12**)

output_tensor = linear_layer(input_tensor)

print("input tensor size：", input_tensor.shape)
print("output tensor size：", output_tensor.shape)

Expected error：
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x12 and 10x5)
Can anyone explain why the results run on GPU and CPU are inconsistent?
Does PyTorch automatically adjust the input size when performing operations on a CUDA GPU?
Does running on GPU affect the training model?
